# How to create a mongoose recursive objects

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io, schema, passport.js

I m trying to create a specific schema with mongoose but i have no clue how to do it, the schema is named "DATAs" which is an object and recursive objects with variable keys "id123443564", "id4252463", id7456345 ...

Here how it must looks like:

```
title : { type : String },
DATAs : {
    "id123443564" : {
        DATA1 : "AZERTY"
        DATA2 : "123456"
    },"id4252463" : {
        DATA1 : "AZERTY"
        DATA2 : "123456"
    },"id7456345" : {
        DATA1 : "QXFZERT"
        DATA2 : "123456"
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Datas：[
  {
     Id: String,
     Data1: String,
     Data2: String
  }
]
```

Comment: I think that the good answer, but in my case its little bit tricky, im using the session object of passport.socketio which is socket.request.user to store some variables, simple variables like title : { type : String } works good, but  when i try to get socket.request.user.Datas i have this result 
[ { _id: 57dc84c79ad43b7427c0fc13 } ]

I dont know if its due to serializeUser & deserializeUser

Comment: I think my session is not supporting brackets, is there other way without brackets ?